# Using R to access Athena - federated account

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, jdbc, saml, amazon-athena

I am trying to download some data from athena (AWS) - my account is managed by SAML authentication.
I managed to get the authentication in place correctly (my credentials are stored in a profile called 'saml')
My problem is actually related to the fetching of data - The table I am querying is only 12000 records and typically it should be very query but it appear to be very slow.

What could be my problem? Is there something wrong with my code ?

```
pkgs <- c('tidyverse',
          'aws.s3',
          'rJava',
          'RJDBC')

# uncomment if needed
#install.packages(pkgs)

#install.packages("aws.signature", repos = c(cloudyr = "http://cloudyr.github.io/drat", getOption("repos")))

# load the packages
lapply(pkgs, library, character.only = TRUE)

URL <- 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.9/AthenaJDBC42_2.0.9.jar'

 # library(rJava)
 # .jinit()
 # .jclassLoader()$setDebug(1L)

fil <- basename(URL)
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)
drv <- JDBC(driverClass="com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver", fil, identifier.quote="'")
provider <- "com.simba.athena.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider"
#provider <- "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain"

Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = aws.signature::locate_credentials()$key)
Sys.setenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = aws.signature::locate_credentials()$secret)
Sys.setenv("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN" = aws.signature::locate_credentials()$session_token)

conn <- dbConnect(drv, 'jdbc:awsathena://athena.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443/',
                  s3_staging_dir="<QUERY-RESULTS-S3-BUCKET>",
                  aws_credentials_provider_class=provider,
                  user = Sys.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
                  password = Sys.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"),
                  aws_credentials_provider_arguments='saml')

# get a list of all tables currently in Athena 
# dbListTables(conn)

# enrich `dbGetQuery` to fetch in batch
setMethod("dbGetQuery", signature(conn="JDBCConnection", statement="character"),  def=function(conn, statement, ...) {
    r <- dbSendQuery(conn, statement, ...)
    on.exit(.jcall(r@stat, "V", "close"))
    if (conn@jc %instanceof% "com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaConnection") fetch(r, -1, 999) # Athena can only pull 999 rows at a time
    else fetch(r, -1)
})

fetch_data <- function(query, path, cache = TRUE) {
    dataset <- dbGetQuery(conn, query)
    if (cache == TRUE) {
        dataset %>%
            write_rds(path)
    } else {
        return (dataset)
    }
}

# 0. Initial setup
clean_schema <- "clean_tst."

# 1. table_1 ----

query <-  str_glue("SELECT * FROM ", 
                   clean_schema, 
                   "table_1")
path = "00_Data/athena/table_1.rds"
fetch_data(query, path)
```

Comment: Have you tried a `dbGetQuery` without all the extra stuff? I use it with Athena without all that extra stuff and it works fine.

Comment: Yes I did, the extra stuff only allow downloading more records in caching mode

Comment: Sorry man. I basically have the same setup otherwise and most basic queries take between 4 and 8 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried loading the results directly from s3(s3 API call) with the query id returned by Athena ?

Comment: Of course but the example I am giving is a toy example - the dataset is multi Gb and I am only selecting a subset. The example is just for illustration purpose but you can assume there are where condition subsetting the data. If I pull the full ORC, parket or csv it will be too heavy to run locally.

Comment: Is the `select * from table` query slow in this toy example? Is this an Athena query tuning issue?

Comment: not at all, when I run the query on athena directly, I get the result in less than 2 seconds